# count_lambda.<locals>.f.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, lambda

```
def count_lambda():
    def f(j):
        return lambda j:j*j
    return [f(i) for i in range(1,4)]

f1, f2, f3 = count_lambda()
print(f1, f2, f3)
print(f1(), f2(), f3())
```

code above occur error when execute, this is the output:

```
<function count_lambda.<locals>.f.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f6729c5e560> <function count_lambda.<locals>.f.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f6729c5e5f0> <function count_lambda.<locals>.f.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f6729c5e680>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/work/go-leetcode/python/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    f1()
TypeError: count_lambda.<locals>.f.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'j'
```

print 1, 4, 6 as expected

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass j to the inner lambda

```
def count_lambda():
    def f(j):
        # the local j in the lambda shadows the j in f(j) so get rid of it
        return lambda j=j:j*j
    return [f(i) for i in range(1,4)]
```

or just dont pass in j to the inner lambda (which should not shadow the outer j)

```
def count_lambda():
    def f(j):
        # the local j in the lambda shadows the j in f(j) so set its default
        return lambda:j*j
    return [f(i) for i in range(1,4)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  the program work as expected after add the code!

I came up with another solution, just change the lambda expression to lambda: j*j